# Validating Journals: by checking publishers or indexing database?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, publishers, withdraw

I have recently submitted a paper to a journal and in the website of that journal it say that indexed in SCOPUS and ESCI and etc. In the website of SCIMAGO the name of the journal is available. When I check the  [scopus website](https://www.scopus.com/sources.uri) there exists a journal by the same name, but when I look for that by ISSN there is no journal with this title. For Emerging sources citation index I have used [ESCI](https://mjl.clarivate.com/home) to validate that. Regarding its publisher, I am not able to validate its publisher because it has just one website with few information. Can you please help me how to validate the journal?

Answer (score 0):

NB: This is for Scimago:

What is on Scimago is what is Scopus indexed.
Check the ISSN on Scimago if it matches.
If it does, the journal site from Scimago should be the right journal. If it is different, then you (might) have an #hijacked journal.

[Edit]
PS: Scimago might not have a broken link: like in the case of the Scandinavian Journal of Information Systems (as at 15 Jun 2023)

[Edit]
Ensure you're checking ISSN and E-ISSN (where there's one).